# Use of PHP explode() function

Tags: php, explode

I have a problem, I want to split a string variable using the explode function but there are a limitation, imagine having the next string variable with the next value :

```
$data = "3, 18, 'My name is john, i like to play piano'";
```

Using the explode function : explode(",", $data), the output will be :

```
array(
       [0] => 3,
       [1] => 18,
       [2] => 'My name is john,
       [3] => i like to play piano'
      );
```

My target is to split the variable $data by comma excluding the ones that are between ' ' chatacters.

e.g. `array(
           [0] => 3,
           [1] => 18,
           [2] => 'My name is john, i like to play piano'
          );`

If anyone can tell me a way to do this, I'd be grateful.

Comment: If your data always has the same structure: explode(",", $data, 3); else str_getcsv()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks rather like CSV data. You can use [str_getcsv](http://php.net/str_getcsv) to parse this.

```
var_dump(str_getcsv("3, 18, 'My name is john, i like to play piano'", ',', "'"));
```

should result in:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(1) "3"
  [1] =>
  string(3) " 18"
  [2] =>
  string(12) "My name is john, i like to play piano"
}
```

You may want to apply `trim` to each of the array elements too, by using `array_map`:

```
$string = "3, 18, 'My name is john, i like to play piano'";
var_dump(array_map('trim', str_getcsv($string, ',', "'")));
```

Answer (score 6):

Use: **[str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)**

```
// set the delimiter with ',', and set enclosure with single quote
$arr = str_getcsv ($data, ',', "'");
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) function as:

```
$data = "3, 18, 'My name is john, i like to play piano'";
$pieces = str_getcsv($data, ',', "'");
```

The first argument to the function is the string to be split.

The second argument is the delimiter on which you need to split.

And the third argument is the single character that when used as a pair (unsescaped) inside the first argument, will be treated as one field, effectively ignoring the delimiters between this pair.